# Logstash optionally set output options for elasticsearch based on fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

Suppose I have some documents with join field, so they may have parent(e.g. [join_field][parent]) field in them, so as per docs, I need to pass that to _routing in logstash elasticsearch output,

```
...
output {
  elasticsearch {
    ...
    routing => "%{[join_field][parent]}"
  }
}
```

Now if there is no join_field in the doc, above will set its routing to literally `%{[join_field][parent]}` in ES.

Is there anyway I can make it optional so the ES output will have routing set only if [join_field][parent] is there?

Or only way here is to have if else condition on the field and have separate output for each(but it feels odd to have multiple ifs for many options)? Also can this have any performance issue?

```
...
output {
  if [join_field][parent] {
    elasticsearch {
      ...
      routing => "%{[join_field][parent]}"
    }
  } else { 
    elasticsearch {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: only evaluating `if[join_field]{parent]  ` is your worry of performance hit? if it is true, it will do the routing that you wanted any way if it is false it gets into to the `else` block anyway. so I don't think this will be a that big of a deal. I don't know any other way also.

Comment: @JBone yeah you're correct on "it'll need to evaluate `[join_field]{parent]` anyway". We are ingesting a lot of documents so I'm getting paranoid about what to put into the config :)

Comment: I totally understand. So if you were to go with this solution, try to make that validation less than half times of the number of documents. What I mean is that use the most occurances scenario in first `if` block and process the `else` where the fewer documents fall in. so in your case, if you think most of the documents would have `routing` info, keep the `if` as is, otherwise reverse the logic.

Comment: @JBone, makes sense, thanks for the help!